# Android: RecyclerView content messed up when i open the app and comes back to normal after scrolling down

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm learning about fragments and i made this app to display a list of recipes, Each row of this list have an image of the recipe and the name of the recipe and i put the recyclerView inside a fragment but the problem is when i open the application the content of the recyclerView gets messed up and returns to normal after scrolling down as shown in the two screenshots below.

[before scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HR6v0.png)

[after scrolling down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZFOM.png)

MainActivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListFragment listFragment = new ListFragment();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.placeHolder, listFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}}
```

ListAdapter class

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter{
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,
            false);
    return new ListViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ((ListViewHolder) holder).bindView(position);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return Recipes.names.length;
}


private class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
     private TextView mRecipeText;
     private ImageView mRecipeImage;
    public ListViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mRecipeImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);
        mRecipeText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemText);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }

    public void bindView(int position) {
        mRecipeText.setText(Recipes.names[position]);
        mRecipeImage.setImageResource(Recipes.resourceIds[position]);
    }
}}
```

listFragment class

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment {
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container , false);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.listRecyclerView);
    ListAdapter listAdapter = new ListAdapter();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    return view;
}}
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/placeHolder"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.elswefi.smellslikebakin.MainActivity">
</FrameLayout>
```

fragment_list.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/listRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/itemImage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/bagels"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="24sp"

        />
</LinearLayout>
```

I hope anyone could help me because i'm still learning and i don't have any idea where this bug came from.

Comment: add your list_item.xml file

Comment: I think the issue is you are adding the fragment. But what you want to do is replace it with `replace()` instead of `add()`.

Comment: add whole code of @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ((ListViewHolder) holder).bindView(position);
}

Comment: @RajeshKushvaha the code is already included in the question,
i'm casting the holder variable to listViewHolder and calling bindView method which in the bottom of main activity class.

Comment: @Barns i tried what you said but still not working

Comment: @AbdelrahmanEl-swefi then how do you set image to imageview?

Comment: @RajeshKushvaha  i set the image at the bindView method which is at the bottom of the  list adapter class

Comment: Try moving this line of code `recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);` to be after this line `recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);` so that you are setting the adapter after setting the layout

Comment: @Barns still not working

Answer (score 1):

**Problem solved**

I solved the problem by adding this line of code 
 `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`
 to the imageView in the list_item.xml file

thank you guys for your comments i really appreciate it.